# Mouse Buttons worked on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, but not 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xorg, mouse

Interesting problem where I seem not to be able to find a solution. I have a 19" rack monitor with integrated mouse and keyboard, Tripp-Lite Part number B021-000-19-HD. On Ubuntu 20.04 the mouse pad works as I can move the mouse, the scroll function works as well, but no right or left click. The libinput driver is detected for it as shown below and `sudo libinput debug-events` as shown below detects the button presses, however in Gnome there is no button press detected. When running xev to test the button presses are not detected. Looking for some help to understand what I have overlooked. On Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 PCs with the HWE kernel these worked. Running currently 5.15.0-53-generic on 20.04.1. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Listing of USB devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2kAO.png)

[Kernel log output showing detected input devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt59n.png)

[Kernel log details on the Mouse Pad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSYBm.png)

[Libinput device listing for Mouse Pad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUuhY.png)

[Xorg.0.log output showing detection of Mouse Pad as pointer with Libinput driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svNbH.png)

[evtest output showing event codes for button presses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLYuG.png)

[Version of libinput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYVVU.png)

[Output of libinput debug-events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs6bw.png)

Comment: If it worked using the HWE kernel of 18.04, why not use that kernel on 20.04?  (ie. use the GA kernel stack on 20.04).

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of the terminal. Always copy the output from the terminal and paste it directly in your question. Then format the pasted output as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: Currently using the HWE kernel on 20.04. Thanks for the feedback on screenshots. Will note for the future. So far still not been able to narrow down the issue. Its not a kernel problem because the libinput driver detects the button presses. The issue is somewhere in XOrg because X11 does not detect as seen by xev. It detects no button presses. I even tested with Wayland and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

we are having a similar problem and it is driving me to the point where I want to bail on the whole thing.

nothing we do, whether it is a gnome tweak or the "settings" utility, fixes the problem such that we can highlight text without trying multiple times or only click the left mouse once before we have to try multiple times.

i can see that there is some improvement based on how the gnome tweaks are set but this occurred all of a sudden (up to date 20.04) some weeks ago and it has been plaguing every since with no combination of adjustments fixing things.

i have searched plenty and found nobody with a real answer other than rebooting and so on and in my case, i have even done that with no solution.

this is a common dell workstation and for a handful of years all has been working well.

i can't keep doing this much longer, so i sure wish someone would shed some meaningful light on this.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1304146)